# Why post on friends wall in facebook via android application return error?

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am using easy facebook lib from [here](http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/)

Error name: E/EasyFacebookAndroid(4882): (#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application

P.S. Post to my wall is work fine.

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776441/facebook-api-spring-social-how-to-post-a-friends-wall

Comment: you should use an Asynchronous thread to publish user's friend wall. i have also fetch that problem. and i use Asynchronous thread to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a new Facebook app recently, which means the February Breaking Changes have already been enabled for your application, which includes the deprecation of posting to friend's wall.

Read my earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829086/oauthexception-when-trying-to-post-to-friends-wall/13830728#13830728)