# Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, oauth

When posting to my friends wall, I got this error:

> Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application.

Do I need to submit my application in Facebook, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776441/facebook-api-spring-social-how-to-post-a-friends-wall

Answer (score 15):

This functionality is in the process of being removed.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013

> **Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API**
>
> We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph
>   API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is
>   different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the
>   target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you
>   want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the
>   feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or
>   action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the
>   friend approves the tag). For more info, see [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/).

Comment: is Graph API only one way to post on friend's wall?

Comment: You can present the user with a Feed dialog, but the Graph API is (was) the only way to do it without user interaction.

Comment: How can i publish offline feeds on friends wall.

Comment: IfTTT.com doing this offline publish how can this possible.

Comment: Not to friends' walls, they're not. They auto-publish to the user's own feed.