# How to send messages to facebook users from windows app

Tags: php, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am looking for a method to send messages to facebook accounts from windows application (e.g. windows service). Of course, all users will grant needed access to my facebook application, but only once - by logging in via facebook on some my web page

First of all, I just tried to send email to `{username}@facebook.com`
But my email was redirected to email of user (has been set when user registered)

Then, I tried to send POST message to `{user_id}/notifications`
(corresponding to [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/notifications) ). But I received `OAuthException: (#200) Only web canvas apps can send app notifications`

Then, I tried to send POST message to `{user-id}/feed`
(corresponding to [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/feed)). But I received `OAuthException` `(#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application`
As I understood from forums, this opportunity was deprecated at 2013
(e.g. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056046/feed-story-publishing-to-other-users-is-disabled-for-this-application) )

When I tried to send a message to `{user-id}/apprequests` then I received an exception

> "Game Requests are only available to games".

I changed category of my App to `Games` and now I am receiving new error

> "Failed to create any app request"

Please prompt me - Is there any way to send any messages to different facebook users from my windows application?

P.S. I develop on C#, but I will be thankful for PHP examples as well

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, post some code that you've tried.

Comment: It is not possible to send messages to Facebook users. Ask for their email and email them